# Dynamically Accessing Java Classes' Member Variables

Tags: java

I have 3 classes with same variable names, but different values. So I am trying to initialise the classes in a common object based on user provided input, then print the corresponding values.

```
public class A {
    public String s1 = "a1";
    public String s2 = "a2";
}

public class B {
    public String s1 = "b1";
    public String s2 = "b2";
}

public class C {
    public String s1 = "c1";
    public String s2 = "c2";
}

//This is not a working code, just a skeleton to express what I am trying to achieve
public class ClassDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String userInput = "A";
        //If it's A, then Class A specific values need to be printed at the end
        //If it's B, then Class B specific values need to be printed at the end
        //If it's C, then Class C specific values need to be printed at the end
        Class clazz;
        switch(userInput) {
        case "A":
            clazz = new A();
            break;
        case "B":
            clazz = new B();
            break;
        case "C":
            clazz = new C();
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Not Implemented");
        }
        System.out.println(clazz.s1);
        System.out.println(clazz.s2);
    }
}
```

I don't want to use following reflection option, as it requires the user to pass variable name as parameter (in example below it's `"s1"`) and it might not be dynamic.

```
Class aClass = A.class;
Field field = aClass.getField("s1");
System.out.println(field.get(new A()).toString());
```

I believe there should be some other better way to handle this type of scenario, but I couldn't figure it out so far. So can someone please give me some suggestions?

Comment: You should be using an interface for situations like this.  More information about using them: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp

Comment: You can do it statically by making your classes implement a common interface that defines the getter methods. No need for reflection.

Comment: Any other options other than interfaces?

Comment: Yes, there's another option. Why not get rid of the duplication in the first place? Why do you need 3 identical classes?

Comment: *be some other better way to handle this type of scenario* ... yes: dont do that. Do **not** directly access fields of objects. You are basically turning OOP into procedural code. Why use objects, when you just treat them as dumb records?!

Comment: Thus my recommendation: step back, and have an experienced person review your design. Because most likely, you are using the complete wrong strategy to solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `interface` which will define an abstract layer of functionality that each of your classes will implement.

When you create an instance of the class that implements the interface, you can ensure that the class supports the subset of functionality you require as it is defined in that interface.

In your case:

```
interface MyInterface { // Name this something sensible
    public String getS1();
    public String getS2();
}

public class A implements MyInterface {
    public String getS1() {
      return "a1";
    }
    public String getS2() {
      return "a2";
    }
}

public class B implements MyInterface {
    public String getS1() {
      return "b1";
    }
    public String getS2() {
      return "b2";
    }
}
```

Later on when using in your code:

```
...
MyInterface clazz; // Please rename this to something more appropriate
switch(userInput) {
    case "A":
        clazz = new A();
        break;
    case "B":
        clazz = new B();
        break;
    case "C":
        clazz = new C();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Not Implemented");
}
System.out.println(clazz.getS1());
System.out.println(clazz.getS2());
```

Answer (score 0):

As several people have commented, using an Interface is often the best approach, since it imposes no other restrictions on your classes.  The other choice, which only works well in some cases, is to pull this common code into a base class, which might be an abstract class if you would never instantiate that base class by itself.

This approach only works well if there is a real is-A relationship, and those common fields really are the same thing in all cases.  e.g. if A is Car, B is Truck, and s1, s2 are fuelType and fuelTankCapacity.  Truck might also have towingWeight, so they are different classes, but they also have a lot in common.  Create a class Vehicle which has the common elements, including the code and business rules which relate to it (like calculating mileage).

Note the important fact that the is-A relationship exists.  A Car "is A" Vehicle;  A Truck "is A" Vehicle.  It is almost always wrong to try to hammer inheritance on a relationship that isn't "is-A".